# Reference is not valid

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro in VBA, but am facing two problems:

1. I keep getting `reference is not valid` error.
2. Horizontal alignment of merged cells does not work.

Here is the sub:

```
Sub test(numCell As Integer)
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim colNum As Integer
    rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
    colNum = ActiveCell.Column
    With Range(Cells(rowNum, colNum), Cells(rowNum, colNum + numCell - 1))
        .Merge (Across)
        .Interior.Color = 200
        .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
        .BorderAround Color:=1
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = 1
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = 1
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = 1
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = 1
        .Borders.Weight = xlThick
        .Value = Str(numCell)
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what is (Across)  is that valid VBA syntax?

Comment: `Across` is an undeclared variable that is empty by default (should be `true` or `false` instead), however this does not change much because it's ultimately converted to `false`. `xlCenterAcrossSelection` does not appear to be a valid value for `VerticalAlignment `, the valid enumeration values begin with `xlVAlign`. For horizontal alignment the value should be `xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection`, but it has the same value as `xlCenterAcrossSelection`. Otherwise the code works for me, although I'd replace the first five lines with `With ActiveCell.Resize(, numCell)`.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors were fixed on these lines: `.Merge` and `.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter`. I think I changed nothing else and the code works.

```
Sub test(numCell As Integer)
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim colNum As Integer
    rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
    colNum = ActiveCell.Column
    With Range(Cells(rowNum, colNum), Cells(rowNum, colNum + numCell - 1))
        .Merge
        .Interior.Color = 200
        .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
        .BorderAround Color:=1
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = 1
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = 1
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = 1
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = 1
        .Borders.Weight = xlThick
        .Value = Str(numCell)
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Got the hint from your previous comment. The error was due to wrong way of calling this sub. I was using run window (F5) and then calling test(4). Now i am entering variable value in cell and getting numCell from ActiveCell. test routine no longer takes value - instead numCell is received as numCell =ActiveCell.Value.